# How can i get parameters form signal which emitted by cpp in QML

Tags: c++, qml

I trigger a signal in .cpp file and parameters of this signal is integer arrays.  Now i can successfully receive this signal in QML,but i don't know how to get the parameters.
My code is just like this:

```
// .h
signals:
    void  mysignal(int a[]);
//.cpp
    int a[]={1,2,3,4,5};
    emit mysignal(a);
// QML
    Connections:{
        target:XXX
        onMysignal:
            // i don't know how to get the parameters here! Anyone can give me tips?
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent for arrays in QML, what is very similar is to use a container like `std::vector` or `QVector`:

```
//.h
signals:
    void  mysignal(const std::vector<int> & a);
//.cpp
    std::vector<int> v = {1,2,3,4,5};
    emit mysignal(v);
//QML
Connections{
    target: XXX
    onMysignal: console.log(a)
}
```

Comment: I have validated your comment, QVector works while std::vector not.I remember you answered my question,thanks a lot.